# VDI resizing api does not work

Tags: php, api, sdk, xen

I am developing a Xen management webapp with Php. The VDI (virtual disk image) renaming API and resizing APIs usage are very same. I haven't managed to succeed resizing the VDI. Do you think what I am doing wrong here.

Renaming function:

```
function xenapi_set_vdi_name($session, $ref, $name)
{
    $conn = $session[0];
    $sess = new xmlrpcval($session[1]);
    $vdi = new xmlrpcval($ref);
    $name = new xmlrpcval($name);
    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg("VDI.set_name_label", array($sess, $vdi, $name));

    $res = $conn->send($msg);

    if ($res->faultcode())
        return false;
    $val = $res->value();
    $status = $val->structmem("Status");
    if ($status->scalarval() != "Success")
        return false;

    $value = $val->structmem("Value");
    return $value->scalarval();
}
```

Renaming working usage:

```
...
xenapi_set_vdi_name($session, $vdi, "NewNameToMyVDI");
...
```

Resizing function:

```
function xenapi_set_vdi_virtual_size($session, $ref, $size)
{
    $conn = $session[0];
    $sess = new xmlrpcval($session[1]);
    $vdi = new xmlrpcval($ref);
    $size = new xmlrpcval($size);
    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg("VDI.set_virtual_size", array($sess, $vdi, $size));

    $res = $conn->send($msg);

    if ($res->faultcode())
        return false;
    $val = $res->value();
    $status = $val->structmem("Status");
    if ($status->scalarval() != "Success")
        return false;

    $value = $val->structmem("Value");
    return $value->scalarval();
}
```

Not working resizing usage:

```
...
$size = '27011707392';
settype($size, "integer");
xenapi_set_vdi_virtual_size($session, $vdi, $size);
...
```

New size value works with XEN command on physical server as:

```
xe vdi-resize uuid="91fe671c-93e1-4162-8128-96fedc3c215c" disk-size="27011707392"
```

Comment: Are you using 32bit system?  `$size = '27011707392';` casted to int will be `2147483647`.

Comment: Xen server is a 32 bit system. My webserver's VPS is 64 bit. You tell me something I never heard. What is the parameter for conversion. Meanwhile `2147483647` didn't work, too.

Comment: I just find out my hypervisor runs as Intel 32bit and webserver runs as AMD 64bit. Does it matter?

Comment: It might for big integers, however if it does not work even with smaller values, try `$val->structmem('ErrorDescription')` to see what's wrong

Comment: `MESSAGE_PARAMETER_COUNT_MISMATCH` error returns with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness: this question was duplicated (see link below) and reported as resolved successfully, so I'm pasting my answer from that question here.

Question:
[VDI resizing api does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325306/vdi-resizing-api-does-not-work)

Answer:
From a quick look at this: http://xen.org/files/XenCloud/ocamldoc/apidoc.html?c=VDI

I think that you should try using either "resize" or "resize online" methods instead of "set virtual size".

Reported as successful with the "resize" method.

Comment: I know. My serverfault question merged with stackoverflow one. So... Thank you again.